# Как подключить телеграм-бот на телеканл?

Tags: node.js, telegram-bot, telegram

Возник такой вопрос как можно добавить телеграм-бот в канал , если являешься админом данного канала. Телеграм бот написана на node js с испольованием telegraf. Подключать через ControllerBot не подходит так как функционал другой. Если у кого-то есть ссылка на статью буду благодарен. Зарание спасибо

Comment: Просто добавьте его в качестве участника. Он автоматически потребует необходимые права и будет получать сообщения из канала.

Answer (score 0):

Зайдите на канал, зайдите в настройки канала:
[image: Настройки]

Выберите "Администраторы":
[image: Администраторы]

Нажмите "Добавить администратора":
[image: Добавить администратора]

Введите имя бота и нажмите на него:
[image: Выбор бота]

Нажмите ОК и настройте права, затем нажмите сохранить